# Variable caching in JavaScript vs. other languages

Tags: java, javascript, caching, compiler-construction

Someone recently told me that this is bad:

```
var el = $("#myID");
$(el).addClass("a");
$(el).addClass("b");
$(el).addClass("c");
```

and that it should be cached like so:

```
var $el = $("#myID");
$el.addClass("a");
$el.addClass("b");
$el.addClass("c");
```

So, my question is, why doesn't it get optimized automatically? In Java and other languages I *think* that the compiler is smart enough to do the caching itself.

i.e., this:

```
// myList is a List<String>
String str = myList.get(0);
String trimmed = str.trim();
String sub = str.substring(0, 5);
boolean abc = str.startsWith("abc");
```

is no more efficient than this:

```
String trimmed = myList.get(0).trim();
String sub = myList.get(0).substring(0, 5);
boolean abc = myList.get(0).startsWith("abc");
```

Can anyone who knows more about compilers give me some insight here? Is JavaScript just stupid like that? Or is it also true for Java/others?

Comment: While a compiler *may* have enough information to infer a function is pure (besides, it isn't as it depends on the DOM - it would require more information, such as knowing no DOM manipulation happens in between the calls, and that's getting out of hand), few actually attempt it. The Java compiler is intentionally stupid, and JIT compilers (both for Java and for JS) are even more constrained by compile time. They usually stick to the most profitable optimizations that don't require lots of analysis (e.g. speculatively remove virtual calls, or in JS assume a static type for some variables).

Comment: If you are concerned about brevity, use the syntactic sugar of jquery:  
`$("#myID").addClass("a").addClass("b").addClass("c");`  

So your code doesn't have to maintain this variable, and it goes out of scope faster.

Comment: @bert Yes obviously... it was just a toy example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(el)` is a relatively expensive function call. The compiler cannot know that it will always return the same (or at least, an equivalent) object for each call, so it cannot make the optimisation you suggest.

This is not necessarily a function of the language. I'm sure there will be languages (perhaps where you can declare a function as idempotent) in which the compiler CAN reason that the return value and do this optimisation.

I'm pretty sure the Java compiler/optimiser can do it for relatively simple cases.

So, for those same simple cases, there's no reason why a Javascript compiler shouldn't do it given the right circumstances. But it's worth considering that the compilation happens in the browser, so there's probably a limit to the amount of CPU time you want to spend doing optimisations so as not to impact the user's browsing experience.

Comment: Sounds like your answer is "maybe JS will optimize, but don't depend on it."

Comment: Pretty good synopsis. There's no reason why it shouldn't for either simple cases or if it's prepared to work hard enough. But, specifically for this jQuery function call, I doubt it would ever succeed.

Comment: 1 more question if you're up for it... Is compiler function inlining a way of doing this sort of optimization? If that's the case, is it true that only pure functions are candidates for inlining?

Answer (score 1):

You think the compiler is smarter than it really is!

Remember that the compiler only really knows about syntax and semantics of the language, not the contract of APIs.  So even though you might know that `$(el)` will always be the same object, all the compiler knows is to "invoke the `$` function with the argument `el`", it can't assume that the function will return the same value given the same argument.  (Think about the `Math.random()` function, for example.)  Similarly, from your Java example, we might know that `myList.get(0)` will always be the same object (usually, unless something else happens, right?) but the compiler cannot.

So yes, it is indeed much more efficient to store a reference to an object retrieved from a function call and act on that reference rather than making the function call repeatedly.